# How to XOR a list of hex numbers

Tags: binary, serial-port, command, hex

I am putting together a list of hex codes for controlling an NEC tv via serial port, and for one of the bytes in every command, I have to XOR the 15 bytes that come before it. This is what the instructions listed:

```
B1 XOR B2 XOR B3 XOR B4 XOR B5 XOR B6 XOR B7 XOR B8 XOR B9 XOR B10 XOR B11 XOR B12 XOR B13 XOR B14 XOR B15
```

So my question is, when written like this, am I supposed to XOR B1 and B2 and then XOR the result of that with B3, or am I completely (and probably) overthinking this?

Answer (score 0):

If your language support this : B1 XOR B2 XOR B3......., yes.

Else

```
Byte[] My15Bytes
Byte Result
For each Byte in My15Bytes
     If Result is not assigned Then
            Result = Byte
     Else
            Result XOR Byte
     EndIf
EndFor

Read Result
```